# how to update value of property of an object through argument variable

Tags: javascript, object, scope, parameter-passing

I would like to increment property `SCountDown` of an object `pomodoro` with 
method `customization`, which has an argument `chooseSession` and this method
 is called within `sessionPlus` method passing `SCountDown` as an argument.
 when i call `sessionPlus` method , `SCountDown` property increments for
 once and when it is called for second time and so on , It doesn't increment.

Here's my code:

```
pomodoro = {   
 SCountDown: 0,
 customization: function(chooseSession) {
    chooseSession++;
     console.log(chooseSession);       
 },
 sessionPlus : function() {
    this.customization(this.SCountDown);        
 }
}
pomodoro.sessionPlus(); // it returns 1 , this is what i needed but
pomodoro.sessionPlus(); // it also returns 1, but what i need is 2.
```

Comment: You cannot pass variables by reference in JavaScript; [all variables are passed by value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605640/javascript-by-reference-vs-by-value). If you want to pass a variable into a function and have that function increment it, you need to pass in an object and increment one of its properties, or rethink your solution so that a pass-by-reference is not required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass `this.SCountDown` to `customization`, you pass its value (which is zero). Then, this value is incremented by 1 and it is outputed. The actual value of  `this.SCountDown` never changes.

JavaScript passes primitives **by value**.
It means that there is no way to modify the primitive by passing it to a function.

```
function modify(a)
{
    a = a * 2;
}

var x = 2;
modify(x);
console.log(x); // 2
```

However, you can modify the inner properties of passed objects since JS uses **call-by-sharing** strategy.
Therefore, you can do the following:

```
function modify(o)
{
    o.val = o.val * 2;
}

var x = { val: 2 };
modify(x);
console.log(x.val); // 4
```

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript uses pass by sharing and since SCountDown is a primitive value (integer) it cannot be referenced in the way you are attempting to. It's always going to log as 1 because you will always be passing in the primitive value 0 and then incrementing that. You need to reference `this.SCountDown` directly instead of `chooseSession`.

```
var pomodoro = {
    SCountDown: 0,
    customization: function(chooseSession) {
        console.log(chooseSession);
    },
    sessionPlus: function() {
        this.SCountDown++;
        this.customization(this.SCountDown);
    }
}

pomodoro.sessionPlus();
pomodoro.sessionPlus();
```

Comment: Thanks @Monica Olejniczak

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. You need increment **this.SCountDown** not **chooseSession**

```js
 pomodoro = {
   SCountDown: 0,
   customization: function(chooseSession) {
     console.log(chooseSession);
   },
   sessionPlus: function() {
     this.SCountDown++;
     this.customization(this.SCountDown);
   }
 }
 pomodoro.sessionPlus();
 pomodoro.sessionPlus();
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

```js
pomodoro = {   
 SCountDown: 0,
 customization: function() {
 
     console.log(this.SCountDown);       
 },
 sessionPlus : function() {
    this.SCountDown=this.SCountDown+1;
    this.customization();        
 }
}
pomodoro.sessionPlus(); // it returns 1 , this is what i needed but
pomodoro.sessionPlus(); // it also returns 1, but what i need is 2.
```

May this help